# Python, how to deal with A(a) when type(a) is yet A

Tags: python, class, idempotent

I need to create a class that mimics this behavior (in mathematics, we say *list*, *dict*, are "idempotent"):

```
>>> list(list([3,4]))
[3, 4]
>>> dict({'a':1,'b':2})
{'a':1,'b':2}
```

So, if *A* is my class, I want to write

```
>>> a = A(1)
>>> b = A(a)
>>> b == a
True
```

I imagine my class A has to look like this :

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self,x):
       if isinstance(x, A) : 
           self = x
       else : 
           self.x = x
           self.y = 'hello'
```

I try it

```
>>> A(1).x
1
>>> A(A(1)).x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'x'
```

It does not work !

I don't want to copy *x* attributes in *self*, i just want *self* to BE *x* or "point" *x*

Some idea ?
Thanks

Comment: `self = x` merely changes the value of the local variable `self` to refer to a different object. (This reference goes away at the end of the method anyway.) It does not *replace* the object that is being pointed to by `self` with the other object.

Comment: In the case of `b = A(a)`, is it also OK that any later changes to `a` affect the value of `b`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`__new__()`](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-April/061426.html) method, which takes is run **before** the class is constructed, as opposed to `__init__()`, which takes place after. With `__new__()` you can hook in and replace the object being created.

```
def __new__(cls, x):
    if isinstance(x, A):
        return x
    else:
        return object.__new__(cls, x)
```

You can't do this in `__init__()` as the object has already been created. Changing `self` simply changes the value of the local variable, it doesn't affect the object.

It's also worth noting that type-checking is almost always the wrong thing to do in Python. Instead, check to see if the class has the information/attributes you need. This way, someone can create a class that acts like yours and works with your code.

As a final word of warning, this is pretty confusing behaviour - people won't expect your class to act like this and it's generally not a great idea. Your example of `list()` and `dict()` isn't accurate to what you are doing here, as `list(some_list)` does not give `some_list`, it gives a new list which is a copy of `some_list` - the same is true for `dict()`:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(x) is x
False
```

When you call a constructor, it's natural to expect a new object, rather than a reference to the existing one. I would recommend making `A(some_a)` copy `some_a`, and restructure your calling code not to rely on `A(some_a) is some_a`).

Comment: +2 if I could for not just answering the question, but also for the excellent advice and explanation.

Comment: Great answer, especially the warning in the last part with a recommendation not do it. It is my understanding that idempotence is a property of certain operations, like an adjective, not an object itself (and since I don't consider _list_ & _dict_ mathematical operations it makes little sense to call them idempotent).

Comment: Ok, very clear answer. I think you are right, the expected behavior of a constructor is to construct some new object. I just have to take care not to call twice my constructor...
Thank you